# How to get request param name itself

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to get only request parameter name:

```
RequestMapping("/test?{state}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(@PathVariable state){
  // if I hit test?CA - state is coming as "est"

}
```

How should I get state?
I don't wanted to make the url /test?state=CA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing path variables and URL parameters.

This ought to work:

```
GET /test/CA

->

@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{state}", method = GET)
public String test(@PathVariable String state){
    // ...
}
```

as would this:

```
GET /test?CA

->

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = GET)
public String test(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters){
    if (parameters.containsKey("CA")) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

as would this:

```
GET /test?state=CA

->

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = GET)
public String test(@RequestParam String state){
    // ...
}
```